# PreparedStatement no inserta datos

Tags: javascript, java, java-swing, java-8, prepared-statements

Buenas tardes:
Solicito la colaboración para resolver el siguiente problema que tengo con dos archivos en java, uno se llama prueba y el otro conexiones, el archivo prueba tiene una tabla que trae los datos desde la base de datos mysql y con un click al botón los inserto en unos Textfield que estan dentro del mismo archivo prueba, los cuales deben de tener los datos a registrar en otra tabla, pero me pide
crear un preparedStatement en el archivo conexión. Aqui están los códigos de los dos archivos, prueba y conexión.

Prueba:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int seleccion = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    //codigo.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 0)));
    //horaVoto.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 1)));
    //estudiante.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 2)));
    codigoCandidato.setText(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccion, 3)));

    int column = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(evt.getX());
    int row = evt.getY()/jTable1.getRowHeight();

    if(row < jTable1.getRowCount() && row>=0 && column < jTable1.getColumnCount() && column >=0){
        Object value = jTable1.getValueAt(row, column);

    if(value instanceof JButton){
            ((JButton)value).doClick();
            JButton boton = (JButton) value;
            System.out.println("Click");


        if(boton.getName().equals("R")){
            System.out.println("Boton Insertar");

          try{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Voto Realizado");
                String query = "insert into voto(codigoVoto,horaVoto,codigoEstudiante,codigoCandidato)values(?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement a=conexion.prepareStatement(query);
                a.setString(1,codigo.getText());
                a.setString(2,horaVoto.getText());
                a.setString(3,estudiante.getText());
                a.setString(4,codigoCandidato.getText());
                a.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Su voto fue registrado");

            }
    catch(HeadlessException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }


        }

        }
    }
}
```

**Archivo Conexión:**

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class conexion {

static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String query) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

}

public String db="votsi";
public String Url="Jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db;
public String User="root";
public String Clave="";

public conexion(){

}

public Connection conectar(){
    Connection link=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        link=DriverManager.getConnection(this.Url,this.User,this.Clave);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }
    return link
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hablas a:

```
conexion.prepareStatement
```

estas llamando el método estático que declaraste en la clase "conexion" y por lo que veo ese método no hace nada. Por eso es que no se pasan los datos.

En este caso lo que tienes que hacer es preparar el statement en "una conexión de verdad", por conexión de verdad me refiero a un objeto de tipo "Connection".

Usando tu clase "conexion" lo que podrías hacer sería crear un objeto de tipo "Connection" dentro de tu ActionListener con ayuda de tu método "conectar". Crear la conexión quedaría así:

```
conexion InstanciaDeTuClase = new conexion(); /*Creas la instancia para poder llamar 
al metodo "conectar"*/

Connection conexionDeVerdad = InstanciaDeTuClase.conectar(); /*Ahora creas una 
instancia de la clase "Connection" con ayuda de tu método "conectar" lo cual 
significa que "conexionDeVerdad" tomara los valores de la variable "link" 
que regresa tu método "conectar".*/
```

Y ahora prepararías el statement con ayuda de tu "conexionDeVerdad"

```
PreparedStatement a = conexionDeVerdad.prepareStatement(query);
```

Si lo haces de esta forma tu codigo debería funcionar.